How to Connect Dropbox with Uppy in a Laravel Project Using JavaScript?
I'm trying to integrate Dropbox with Uppy in my Laravel project. I'm using JavaScript and jQuery. However, when I attempt to connect, I'm redirected back to the connection page. Below is the code I'm using
import { Uppy, Dashboard, GoogleDrive, ImageEditor, Webcam, Tus, ScreenCapture, Audio, Dropbox, Instagram, Url, Unsplash, Box } from "https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v3.27.3/uppy.min.mjs"

const uppy = new Uppy()
    .use(Dropbox, { 
        target: Dashboard,
        companionUrl: "https://api2.transloadit.com/companion",
        companionHeaders: {
            Authorization: "Bearer sl.B5FeAU9eS-eU1lnxfH3bRt8PpBtaBH5HQ3gjQQsDxu1TzhzVmvixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    });

Despite this, it's not working correctly. Could someone please help me understand what might be going wrong and how to fix it?
Details:

I'm using Laravel.
I have included the necessary scripts and modules as shown above.
The authorization token is correctly set (I replaced part of it with 'xxxx' for security).

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
